# Integration of $\int f(x)^n dx$? Integration by substitution or power rule?

Tags: integration, substitution

So I noticed that there's an occasion when integration by substitution is "simpler" than integration by substitution.

The integral I'm having is

$$\int_{x_0}^x (t-x_0)^n dt, \space t, x_0, x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Now to use integration by substitution on this one defines $f(t)=t^n$ and $g(t)=t-x_0$ and writes

$$=\int_{x_0}^x (t-x_0)^n \cdot 1\space dt$$

$$= \int_{x_0}^{x} f(g(t))g'(t)dt$$

And by integration by substitution formula

$$=\int_{g(x_0)}^{g(x)} f(u) du$$

$$=\int_{0}^{x-x_0} f(u) du$$

$$=\int_{0}^{x-x_0} u^n du$$

And it turns out that in this case one can use the power formula

$$\int u^n = \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} + C_1, \space u\in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Now the question is, is this some general property of certain kinds of integral of powers? That one can directly use the power rule interpreted like

$$\int f(x)^n dx = \frac{f(x)^{n+1}}{n+1} + C_2$$

or

$$\int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C_3, \space x \in \mathbb{R}$$

rather than use integration by substitution?

Or does the inner function have to be of first order (with or without added constants and without a multiplicative constant acting on the variable) so that one gets the inner function derivative $g'(x)=1$?

Comment: How many possibilities do you have to visit e.g. Rome ? And one route can be more pleasant than the other one. It's the same, if you like to integrate. You have some rules - use them as you like. For some simple problems exist of course standard methods (as in your case: both rules, which you have used). But often it's "try and error" to find out which is suitable. The most important is: To know how to use the integration rules correctly.

Comment: How can integration by substitution be "simpler" than integration by substitution?